# Find between which row some number belongs

Tags: r, match

I am trying to create a function to find out where some number matches between rows of a column in a dataframe:

**Data:**

```
df = data.frame("one"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),"two"=c(8,9,10,11,12,13,14))
```

**Attempt:**

```
fun_match_one <- function(value_to_match, data) {

  if(value_to_match<data$one[1]) {row=1}
  else {

    row=which((value_to_match>=data$one) == (value_to_match<c(tail(data$one,-1),Inf)))
  }
  return(row)

}
```

So for example the *value_to_match* = 6.5 goes between 6 and 7, thus we get a match of the row where 6 is located. I just find my solution to be so ugly, and hope somebody can help to make this more R-elegant.

**EDIT**: not using the second column of df to anything at this moment.

**EDIT2**: Expected output if value_to_match is lower than lowest value of column, is the lowest value of the column, and similar for the highest value of the column if the value_to_match is higher than the higher value of the column. As you see I have integrated this into my solution, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. findInterval-function in R only handles columns that are strictly increasing, which is not my case always.

Comment: Take a look at `?findInterval`. You likely want `findInterval(value_to_match, data$one, all.inside=TRUE)`.

Comment: this does not solve for values that are smaller than first value, though

Comment: Why not? It returns 1 exactly like your function.

Comment: findInterval(-10,4:10)

Comment: Did you read my comment? Did you see the argument `all.inside=TRUE`?

Comment: Easy there! Didn't see you edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function as

```
fun_match <- function(data, value_to_match,col) {
    max(tail(which(value_to_match >= data[col]), 1), 1)
}

fun_match(df, 6.5, "one")
#[1] 6

fun_match(df, 12.2, "two")
#[1] 5

fun_match(df, 2.5, "one")
#[1] 2
```

Comparing it with `fun_match_one`

```
fun_match_one(-21, df)
#[1] 1
fun_match(df, -21, "one")
#[1] 1

fun_match_one(21, df)
#[1] 7
fun_match(df, 21, "one")
#[1] 7

fun_match_one(2.5, df)
#[1] 2
fun_match(df, 2.5, "one")
#[1] 2
```

Comment: tail(which(4.6 > df["one"]), 1) returns wrong number, so I think solution is too simple?

Comment: @Erosennin for the example you have shared 6.5 goes between 6 and 7 and you return the index of lower boundary which is 6. Similarly, 4.6 goes between 4 and 5 and running `tail(which(4.6 > df["one"]), 1)`  gives you index of lower boundary which is 4. What do you expect as an answer here?

Comment: I should be more clear, sorry: what I'm saying is that fun_match(df, 6.5, "one") does not give you the same result as fun_match(df, 6, "one"), which is not correct

Comment: in that case, change the sign from `>` to `>=` ? Updated the answer. Now `fun_match(df, 6, "one")` and `fun_match(df, 6.5, "one") ` both return 6.

Comment: still: fun_match(df,-44,"one") returns integer(0) . but you could not know that I needed that.

Comment: @Erosennin I have updated the answer. Seems to work now same as `fun_match_one` in various cases. Let me know if I have missed any.